# Shell script to copy every 512 bytes from a file

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, bash-scripting

I have an input file of size 1040 bytes. I need to copy the first 512 bytes, skip next 8 bytes and copy the next 512 bytes, skip 8 bytes.

I am able to copy the first 512 using dd command, but not sure how to put this in shell script to skip 8 bytes and copy the next 512 bytes.

Any help please

Comment: Does it specifically have to be a shell script? That's just making things unnecessarily harder...

Comment: Hint: `dd` has a `skip` argument.

Comment: Hi. Any other language responses are also appreciated. !! But shell script is the first choice..

Comment: `bs=8 skip=65 count=64`